# How to make my PC become an "psudo/fake" external display for android phone via USB ports (without using any USB to HDMI dongles)

Tags: android, linux, windows, usb, hdmi

I want my Android phone to recognize my PC as its external display (psuedo/fake or virtual displays) via USB connection (USB-C - USB-A cable or TCP connection) without using any USB to HDMI dongles or wifi display like miracast either.

I think I need to find or write the app/software or driver on PC side which have USB protocol like any real USB-C to HDMI display to communicate with the phone.
Do you have any suggestion or guidelines?

Thanks,

Comment: start with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/VirtualDisplay

Comment: Voting to close as requests for recommendations are off topic here. Recommend you delete here and post to [android.se] or [su] or [softwarerecs.se]. Good luck.